# Swift 'Required String parameter 'grant_type' is not present' error when trying to get an access token

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0

So I'm trying to make an app in Swift for which I need to login to the OAuth to retrieve an access token. The API takes the parameters 'grant_type' and 'code'.

I've tried:

```
let params = ["grant_type":"authorization_code", "code":"123456789"] as Dictionary<String, String>

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://myschool.zportal.nl/api/v3/oauth/token")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        print(json)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
})

task.resume()
```

This returns:

```
["response": {
    data =     (
    );
    details = "class org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'grant_type' is not present";
    endRow = 0;
    eventId = 216795;
    message = "Internal problems.";
    startRow = 0;
    status = 500;
    totalRows = 0;
}]
```

This is weird, because I did parse the 'grant_type' parameter, and as the correct value.

It should return something like:

```
{
  "response": {
    "status":200,
    "message":"",
    "startRow":0,
    "endRow":27,
    "totalRows":27,
    "data":[
      {
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working:

```
@IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let urlString = "https://myschool.zportal.nl/api/v3/oauth/token"
        performRequest(urlString: urlString)

    }
    
    func performRequest(urlString: String) {
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=1234567890".data(using: .utf8)
            
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
                //print(response!)
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print("error")
                }
            })
            
            task.resume()
            
        }
        
    }
```

Not the nicest code but I'll polish it later.
At first I parsed JSON but it turned out I needed to parse a String and turn it into a Data type using: `.data(using: .utf8)`

Answer (score 1):

The standard message format requires a Form URL Encoded body, not a JSON one. Maybe adapt your code as in [this Swift article](https://medium.com/@serge.works.io/swift-how-to-create-a-http-post-request-with-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-body-bfd9cd26d6d5).